# How to automate a field mapping using a table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one column table in my snowflake database that contain a JSON mapping structure as following

```
ColumnMappings : {"Field Mapping": "blank=Blank,E=East,N=North,"}
```

How to write a query that if I feed the `Field Mapping` a value of `E` I will get `East` or if the value if `N` I will get `North` so on and so forth without hard coding the value in the query like what `CASE` statement provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want your mapping in this JSON form:

```
{
  "blank" : "Blank",
  "E" : "East",
  "N" : "North"
}
```

You can achieve that in Snowflake e.g. with a simple JS UDF:

```
create or replace table x(cm variant) as
select parse_json(*) from values('{"fm": "blank=Blank,E=East,N=North,"}');

create or replace function mysplit(s string)
returns variant
language javascript
as $$
res = S
  .split(",")
  .reduce(
    (acc,val) => {
      var vals = val.split("=");
      acc[vals[0]] = vals[1];
      return acc;
    },
    {});

return res;
$$;

select cm:fm, mysplit(cm:fm) from x;
-------------------------------+--------------------+
             CM:FM             |   MYSPLIT(CM:FM)   |
-------------------------------+--------------------+
 "blank=Blank,E=East,N=North," | {                  |
                               |   "E": "East",     |
                               |   "N": "North",    |
                               |   "blank": "Blank" |
                               | }                  |
-------------------------------+--------------------+
```

And then you can simply extract values by key with [GET](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/get.html), e.g.

```
select cm:fm, get(mysplit(cm:fm), 'E') from x;
-------------------------------+--------------------------+
             CM:FM             | GET(MYSPLIT(CM:FM), 'E') |
-------------------------------+--------------------------+
 "blank=Blank,E=East,N=North," | "East"                   |
-------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

For performance, you might want to make sure you call `mysplit` only once per value in your mapping table, or even pre-materialize it.

Comment: Splitting the keys/values and creating a dictionary from it is what will do it. Thank you!